# Unintentional DJI Gimbal Yaw rotation during missions

Tags: swift, dji-sdk

The problem is that during waypoint missions the drone (Mavic 2 Pro) rotates its gimbal yaw 90 degrees to the left.  The issue itself does not seem to be specifically related to our application, I have confirmed the issue as a potential outside issue by factory restoring the drone and controller, updating to the newest firmware, calibrating the gimbal, compass and IMU. Finally, confirming the issue as not specifically the application I tested with the DJI GO app and configured a mission the yaw issue persisted.

The problem is not present during manual flights, using the controller and mobile device the gimbal behaves normally and can be controlled to look in any direction, this in my opinion demonstrates that no hardware issue could be responsible.
Any help regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.